# Labelling a coloured area under a graph

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, label, legend

I would like to be able to display a label in the legend box for a coloured area under a graph. The coloured area is between 13 < x < 17 and 22 < x < 29

I am using:

```
for i in data.findOne()
    a = [element['total'] for element in i['counts']]
    P.plot(a, label="curve 1", color='green')
    where = np.zeros(len(a),dtype=bool)
    where[13:17] = True
    where[22:29] = True
    P.fill_between(np.arange(len(a)),a,where=where,color='green', alpha='0.5')

P.legend()
P.show()
```

Where could I insert a command to show a legend for it? I would like the legend for the shaded area to be in the same legend box as the one for the curve.

Thank you!

This is what it looks like:

[image: example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PolyCollection, as returned by `fill_between`, is not supported by the current label mechanism. What you can do is create an arbitrary patch as Proxy Artist and add this as placeholder, e.g.:

```
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import numpy as np
import pylab as P

xs = np.arange(0,10,0.1)
line1 = P.plot(xs,np.sin(xs),"r-", label="lower limit")[0]
line2 = P.plot(xs,np.sin(xs-1)+3,"b-", label="upper limit")[0]
P.fill_between(xs,np.sin(xs), np.sin(xs-1)+3,color='green', alpha=0.5, label="test")
rect = Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc="g", alpha=0.5)
P.legend([line1, line2, rect], ["lower limit", "upper limit", "green area"])
P.show()
```

gives us:
[image: Sample]

For reference, see [this](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#using-proxy-artist)

Comment: Would that work if I wanted to colour 2 distinct areas under the curve? (see screenshot above)

Comment: Sure - I do not expect you want to have to legend-entries for areas with same color, do you? I edited my example to better fit your changed question.